# Changing the color of a shape every 5 seconds in excel using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Hello I am looking for the VBA code to change the color of a shape in Excel using VBA every 5 seconds from when I click a button. the name of my shape is "Rectangle 1".

Comment: why? [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319683/vba-macro-on-timer-style-to-run-code-every-set-number-of-seconds-i-e-120-secon)

Answer (score 0):

Assign your button to run **StartTimer:**

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 5
Public Const cRunWhat = "qwerty"

Sub StartTimer()
RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, procedure:=cRunWhat, _
     schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime earliesttime:=RunWhen, _
       procedure:=cRunWhat, schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1")
    s.Fill.ForeColor.SchemeColor = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 20)
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```